# How do we detect a redis failure, in Java?

Tags: caching, redis

When the lookup for a redis key fails (using zrangeByScore for example), it could be either because the key does not exist or because the redis lookup failed. So, how does one detect a redis failure, in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Call Redis' [`EXISTS`](http://redis.io/commands/exists) to distinguish between an empty response and a non-existent key.

Comment: If the key does not exist, then `EXISTS` will return 0 right? What do you mean by an empty response. Does it throw an exception?
Can you please provide an example in Java? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Java :)

Comment: No problem! But can you explain what an empty response is? Or would it throw an error?

Comment: An empty response is just that - you'd probably get a null, but an exception is unlikely.

Comment: Thanks! I found this: http://tool.oschina.net/uploads/apidocs/jedis-2.1.0/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html#exists(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

By Redis failure if you mean a network or server issue, then you can put your code in a try, catch block and look for an exception.

exists call to Redis will check for a missing key. Also note that for Redis a missing key and an empty set are the same. So if you remove the last member of a sorted set via zrem, the key is automatically deleted.